# How to acces a ng-model from another HTML file?

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a `index.html` file with this:

**Index.html**

```
<div>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="showModal()" href="#">Add Widget</a>
    <label>Edit mode</label>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="edit">
</div>
```

And a file called **Bar.html**

```
<div>
    <i ng-show="edit" class="fa fa-trash icon-options"></i>
    <i ng-show="edit" class="fa fa-cog icon-options"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-refresh icon-options"></i>
    <i ng-hide="loading" class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin icon-options"></i>
    <div class=Bar></div>
</div>
```

When I click on the checkbox it must hide the icons. This works when I put all the code in **Index.html**. I want to write cleaner code so I decided to separate the files. It doesn't work when I separate the file.

Is there a way to acces the `ng-model="edit"` from the **Bar.html** file?

Kind regards

UPDATE dashboard controller:

```
generalApp.controller('DashBoardcontroller', ['$scope', '$mdDialog', '$http', '$element', function ($scope, $mdDialog, $http, $element) {

this.$onInit = function (){
   $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'Dashboard/GetDashboard'
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            $scope.dashboard = response.data;
            // var widgets = tryJsonConvert($scope.dashboard.Widgets);
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });

}
}]);
```

And the parts where everything is in **Index.html**

```
<div>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="showModal()" href="#">Add Widget</a>
    <label>Edit mode</label>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="edit">
</div>
<div>
<i ng-show="edit" class="fa fa-trash icon-options"></i>
    <i ng-show="edit" class="fa fa-cog icon-options"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-refresh icon-options"></i>
    <i ng-hide="loading" class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin icon-options"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: can you add the part where all this gets together? (do you include `Bar.html` from `Index.html` and if so, how? Are they both included in another html view? Is `Bar.html` injected in the modal?)

Comment: Can you provide a controller where the model is handled?

Comment: I updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add your desired code in bar.html and include the file in following way.

**index.html**

```
<div>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="showModal()" href="#">Add Widget</a>
    <label>Edit mode</label>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="edit">
    <div ng-include="'file_path of bar.html'">
    </div>
</div>
```

**bar.html**

```
<i ng-show="edit" class="fa fa-trash icon-options"></i>
    <i ng-show="edit" class="fa fa-cog icon-options"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-refresh icon-options"></i>
    <i ng-hide="loading" class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin icon-options"></i>
</div>
```